# Any efficient way to create a multidimensional mask with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to replace a specific color like below

```
mask=img==color
img[mask]=newcolor
```

but obviously the mask is a 2D 3 color array so the following error will be raised

```
TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions
```

Creating for loop like below can be a solution but it is not efficient

```
mask=np.zeros(img.shape[:2]).reshape(-1).astype(np.bool_)
for i,m in enumerate((img==np.array(color)).reshape(-1,len(img[0,0]))):
        mask[i]=np.sum(m)==len(img[0,0])
```

I do know that opencv do have a function to create mask like

```
mask=cv2.inRange(img, np.array(color), np.array(color))
```

but I want to know how can I make it with numpy only

Comment: I tried tried `x = np.random.random((20, 20)); x[x < .5] = 0` and it worked fine.  There's no reason `img[img == color] = newcolor` shouldn't work.

Comment: @FrankYellin ```x = np.random.random((20,20,3)); x[x < .5]=np.zeros([1,3])```  will not work, if I want to replace it with the 3 channel color.

Comment: In your original question, is `color` a single value or an array of size 3?  That's maybe what confused me.  Because `x[x < .5] = 0` works fine, but they may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry I mean ```x[x<np.array([0.5,0.5,0.5])]=np.array([255,255,255])```

Comment: @FrankYellin it is an array of size 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logical and to reduce (`ndarray.all()` method) the last axis of `mask`:

```
>>> img.shape
(438, 313, 3)
>>> color.shape
(3,)
>>> mask = (img == color).all(-1)
>>> mask.shape
(438, 313)
>>> newcolor.shape
(3,)
>>> img[mask] = newcolor
>>>
```